# Swift: Why does switching over textfields work?

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement

For example:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    switch textField {
    case stateField:
        print("editing state")
    case countryField:
        print("editing country")
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Is it because its looking at address for those fields? Is this a right way to use switch statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under the hood, the `switch` statement uses the [pattern matching operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-ID426) (`~=`) in order to define the comparisons it can do. In your case, it's using [this version](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StandardLibrary_Operators/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/opfunc/s:ZFsoi2teuRxs9EquatablerFTxx_Sb):

```
@warn_unused_result
public func ~=<T : Equatable>(a: T, b: T) -> Bool
```

This takes two `Equatable` arguments of the same concrete type. In the switch statement, each case is passed into `a`, and the statement to switch on is passed into `b`. The `Bool` it returns defines whether the case should get triggered, in this case it will return the value of `a == b`.

`UITextField` inherits from `NSObject`, which conforms to `Equatable` via `isEqual`. Therefore it is valid to use two `UITextFields` for this operator, and therefore perfectly valid to use them in a `switch`.

As its base implementation, `isEqual` just checks for pointer equality. Therefore your switch statement is indeed simply checking that your given `UITextField` is the exact same instance as a given case.

You could also think about as doing this:

```
if textField == stateField {
    print("editing state")
} else if textField == countryField {
    print("editing country")
} else {
    // 'default' case
}
```

Which is just doing this (in the case of `NSObject` inherited classes):

```
if textField.isEqual(stateField)  {
    print("editing state")
} else if textField.isEqual(countryField) {
    print("editing country")
} else {
    // 'default' case
}
```

Using a `switch` here is great usage – it makes your code much clearer than chaining lots of `if` & `else if` statements together.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Thats what I thought. I wasn't exactly sure if thats a valid, so its good to hear that this is a valid usage.

Comment: This is actually a really great example of the power of the Swift switch statement as opposed to, say, C's version.